# How can access toolbar menu item from ViewHolder

Tags: java, android, android-viewholder

I can easily access any `TextView` or `CardView` from adapter but if `I want to access toolbar menu item`, It gives an error, How can I access `toolbar menu item` from outside adapter in onBindviewHolder, like this [docs](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/database/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/database/fragment/PostListFragment.java#L101).

```
public class SoruDoldurucu extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

    public CardView cevapA,cevapB,cevapC,cevapD,cevapE;
    public TextView a,b,c,d,e,Soru;
    public MenuItem fav;
    ViewStub stub;
    public SoruDoldurucu(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        Soru = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Soru_text);
        stub = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_stub);
        stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.siklargrid);
        stub.inflate(); 

        cevapA = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView_A);
        cevapB = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView_B);
        cevapC = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView_C);
        cevapD = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView_D);
        cevapE = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView_E);

     fav = itemView.findViewById(R.id.favorite); // if I write this line it gives error null pointer
```

Comment: why you want to access tollbar here?

Comment: I want to add a favorite button, for example if user want see it later

Comment: send toolbar as parameter to your adapter

Comment: you can't findViewById for a Menu item ... `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) then menu.getItem(n)`

Answer (score 0):

You should acces Toolbar from your Fragment or Acrivity only. To do so create listener implementing methods that will cover requested functionality like this:

```
interface ToolbarListener {

    void accesToolbarAndDoSomething();
}
```

Make your Fragment or Activity implement it and pass "this" as an argument to your RecyclerView.Adapter:

```
public class SoruDoldurucuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter (...) {

    ToolbarListener listener;

    public SoruDoldurucu (... , ToolbarListener listener) {
       this.listener = listener;
    }

    public class SoruDoldurucu extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public SoruDoldurucu(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                Soru = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Soru_text);
                stub = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_stub);
                button.setOnClickListener(() -> listener.accesMenuAndDoSomething());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an NPE because the view that you're passing to your ViewHolder class doesn't have the toolbar (or, an id named "favorite").
Your toolbar is probably in a fragment or activity, to update it, make a listener and send some data in your onBindViewHolder to the parent and update the UI there.